# textFieldDidBeginEditing: for more than one textfield

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitextfield

I am fairly new to iphone programming and here I am facing some issues. Now in my application, I have two textfields and I want to fire an event while second textfield starts editing. now I am using following function

`- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField`

but the thing is the event is being fired when the first textfield starts editing. It does not wait for the second text field. Is there any way I can use this function for the second textfield or may be somehow could know and pass it the value of the active textfield?

I tried writing the name of the textfield instead of (UITextField *)textField in the function but still the same result.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If I were you , I would set a tag (in Interface Builder) of the second `textField` to 2, or something similar.  Then you can just do this:

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {     
    if (textField.tag == 2) {
        //this is textfield 2, so call your method here
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT**: Please do this to see if the method is even called:

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {     
    NSLog(@"The method was called");
}
```

For **Swift 2.2**

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    if textField.tag == 2 {
        //this is textfield 2, so call your method here
    }
}
```

Comment: hi thanks for reply. but can I add tags to UITextfields as I am not using Interface Builder. I am doing the whole thing programmatically. is it possible in that case?

Comment: @Vik, you can set in code: `button.tag = 2` or `[button setTag:2]`

Comment: Hi, I actually tried setting textfield tag by locationText.tag =2 and then checking condition by if(textField.tag == 2) in textFieldDidBeginEditing: but it didn't work. same thing, the event didn't get fire.

Comment: @Vik Put a NSLog in the in an empty `textFieldDidBeginEditing:` method, and see if it even gets called.  Something might be wrong with your delegates.

Comment: @sudo rm -rf ,@ blackfrog -its still not working. I am setting the tag using locationText.tag = 2 but when I print that in didBeginEditing, it shows nothing in that tag value so I am not sure but the event is being called when i run it without the tag but ofcourse on wrong textfield. any suggestions?

Comment: @Vik: Check my edit and please try it out.  Let me know if you get a message in the console.

Answer (score 16):

That delegate method is gonna get called everytime the editing of ANY text field is started, so it should be you who controls what is done when this happens. I suggest you to do something like:

```
   -(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing: (UITextField *)textField
   {     
        if (textField == mySecondTextField)
        {
            //Do what you need
        }
        else
        {
            //Do nothing
        }
   }
```

I hope it helps you!

Comment: I totally get it and thats what I am trying to do but now that event is not being fired. Is this the right way to check the value of the textfield becuase I don't think textField has anything in the following code. Please check my code and see whats wrong coz now the event is not getting fired at all -(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *) textField
{ 
 if(textField == locationText)
 {
    //Doing stuff
 }                                                            Thanks

Comment: Make sure the view controller implements the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol and ,as AhmadTK said, you told the text field that the view controller is its delegate. Maybe to get things a little clearer, you should read about the subject, protocols, delegation and stuff.

Comment: @Vik Did you finally get it to work? I hope you did. Please accept the answer that helped you the most. Thanks

Comment: no its still not working. I am setting the tag using locationText.tag = 2 but when I print that in didBeginEditing, it shows nothing in that tag value so I am not sure but the event is being called when i run it without the tag but ofcourse on wrong textfield. any suggestions?

Comment: Better to check by ``[textField isEqual: mySecondTextField]``

Answer (score 4):

Utilitize the [tag property](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html) in Interface Builder to identify your view objects in your application at runtime. It will make life a lot easier, especially when you get ready to localize your application for different languages.

[image: Screenshot of the tab property in IB]

In your header file for your view controller

```
#define kUsernameField 100
#define kPasswordField 101
#define kStartButton 300
```

In the view controller implementation file

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    switch (textField.tag) {
        case kUsernameField:
            // do user name stuff
            break;

        case kPasswordField:
            // do password stuff
            break;

        default:
            NSLog(@"No case statement for %@", [textField description]);
            break;
    }    
}
```

You will find a lot of tutorial out there that use the title field of UIButton to identify them. For example:

```
- (IBAction)buttonTouchUp:(id)sender {
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;

    // don't like
    if ([button.currentTitle isEqualToString:@"Start"] == NSOrderedSame) {
        // because if localize your for other language then you will have
        // include code for those other language
        //     French: Démarrer
        //     Spanish: Inicio
        // blah blah blah
    }

    // better
    if (button.tag == kStartButton) {
        // very simple, no code changes for localization
        // blah blah blah
    }

}
```

If you are creating the object with code, you can set the tag:

```
button.tag = kStartButton;
// or
[button setTag:kStartButton];
```

Comment: I particularly dislike the concept of using the Interface builder to set the tag property because now you have the ids of the elements in two very different places, which might make it very hard to maintain. I advise you to set the tag property within the code in order to avoid inconsistencies.

Comment: What about objects that I don't connect with IBOutlet?  I don't connect every UIButton back to the view controller. THat is another reason I like the tag property.

Comment: Hi, I actually tried setting textfield tag by locationText.tag =2 and then checking condition by if(textField.tag == 2) in textFieldDidBeginEditing: but it didn't work. same thing, the event didn't get fire.

Comment: Yeah I see that it might come in handy, it's just that I don't like having identifiers in two different places just because they could easily get messed up.

Comment: @Vik in code when you create the UITextField you set the delegate property to your view controller?

Comment: whether you set the tag in IB or in code is personal preference (I do everything in code). regardless, tags are the way to go.

Comment: @xjones -its still not working. I am setting the tag using locationText.tag = 2 but when I print that in didBeginEditing, it shows nothing in that tag value so I am not sure but the event is being called when i run it without the tag but ofcourse on wrong textfield. any suggestions?

Comment: @Vik, if you are setting the `tag` property when creating the label and you are setting the label's `delegate` property to your view controller (most likely `self`) then this will work.

Comment: @xjones - Thanks a lot. It actually worked. I was just doing something stupid. I just set the delegate right and it worked. Thanks

Comment: This deserves to be the answer to be honest.  He put more work into it than I did. :)

Answer (score 2):

You must declare first `UITextFieldDelegate` in your controller `.h`

And set the delegate of your text field. ex. `myInput.delegate = self;`

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)sender
{
    if ([sender isEqual:myInput])
    {
        NSLog(@"test");

    }
}
```

This works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked if your second textViews delegate is set to self ? I had the same issue where I had forgotten to set the delegate of other textFields and hence the delegate method was not firing.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look to my answer in this Question, it's exactly what you're looking for
[Objective C: what is a "(id) sender"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5578139/objective-c-what-is-a-id-sender/5578158#5578158)

Comment: @Ahmad, I totally get it and thats what I am trying to do but now that event is not being fired. Is this the right way to check the value of the textfield becuase I don't think textField has anything in the following code. Please check my code and see whats wrong coz now the event is not getting fired at all -(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *) textField
{ 
 if(textField == locationText)
 {
    //Doing stuff
 }                                                            Thanks

Comment: the UITextField you're expecting the event to fire is built through the .XIB file or you add it dynamically ?

Comment: I am adding it programmatically. I am not using Interface Builder at all.

Comment: have you set the Delegate of the UITextField? yourTextField.delegate = self;

Comment: your Owner header file have <UITextFieldDelegate>?

Comment: @ahmad - yes it has that but still not working. I am setting the tag using locationText.tag = 2 but when I print that in didBeginEditing, it shows nothing in that tag value so I am not sure but the event is being called when i run it without the tag but ofcourse on wrong textfield. any suggestions?