# Does every action method need a sender object?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ibaction

Can I just omit the parameter completely? I cannot seem to find a use for it within my IBAction method.

Comment: You'd use this if you had 2 objects which were calling that selector and you wanted to distinguish between them.http://stackoverflow.com/a/5578158/944634

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can omit it if you don't want it:

```
-(IBAction)action{
    // some stuff
}
```

Although it can come in handy in a lot of situations

Source : [Apple Doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CommunicatingWithObjects/CommunicateWithObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH7-SW44)

Comment: [inputBox addTarget:self 
                 action:@selector(display:nil)
       forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit];        because unfortunately this is not syntactically correct somehow

Comment: [inputBox addTarget:self action:@selector(display) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit]; is, if the method is defined like -(void)display{ // stuff }

Comment: Oh wow, I see, I sort of had that earlier before adding nil, had a leftover colon. Thank you Olotiar.