# PresentViewController from custom TableCell in xib

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimagepickercontroller

I've created custom tableView Controller, inside the cell i've placed a button to open the device photo library. My problem, i cant able to open imagePickerController from CustomCell.m, its shows below error.  [image]

Please give some idea to fix my issue.

Comment: use delegate pattern to bind your cell with viewcontroller.

Comment: Can you elaborate your answer? @NeilGaliaskarov

Answer (score 32, accepted):

TableViewCell is a view, you can not `present` on views instead UIViewController can handle it. You should transfer the control from your cell to your controller that holds tableview and creates custom cell for it.

Try like this:

Custom Cell `.h` Class:

```
@protocol changePictureProtocol <NSObject>
-(void)loadNewScreen:(UIViewController *)controller;
@end

@property (nonatomic, retain) id<changePictureProtocol> delegate;
```

Then `Synthesize it in`.m.

Add this in `m` file:

```
-(IBAction)changePicture:(id)sender
{
    // ..... blah blah
    [self.delegate loadNewScreen:picker];
}
```

The viewcontroller that loads this cell:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   // create cell here

   cell.delegate = self;
}

-(void)loadNewScreen:(UIViewController *)controller;
{
  [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Its a psuedocode to give you an idea.

**EDIT:**

Swift equivalent:

`CustomTableViewCell.swift` code:

```
protocol ChangePictureProtocol : NSObjectProtocol { 
    func loadNewScreen(controller: UIViewController) -> Void;  
}

class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    // Rest of the class stuff

    weak var delegate: ChangePictureProtocol?

    @IBAction func changePicture(sender: AnyObject)->Void
    {
        var pickerVC = UIImagePickerController();
        if((delegate?.respondsToSelector("loadNewScreen:")) != nil)
        {
           delegate?.loadNewScreen(pickerVC);
        }  
    }
}
```

`ViewController.swift` code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellIdentifier") as CustomTableViewCell!

    cell.delegate = self;

    return cell;
}

func loadNewScreen(controller: UIViewController) {
    self.presentViewController(controller, animated: true) { () -> Void in

    };
}
```

Comment: Hey, would you mind explaining this in Swift? Having trouble converting it from objc from your explanation. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @lukesIvi, check my edits for swift equivalent and let me know if you have any difficulty.

Comment: swift is not work for me, i tried to show print(delegate) but it only "nil"
here is my code:
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        print("Hello outside")
        print(delegate)
        if((delegate?.respondsToSelector("loadNewScreen:")) != nil)
        {
            print("Hello insinde")
            let details = MovieDetail();
            delegate?.loadNewScreen(details);
            print(delegate)
        }
    }

Comment: @EvanNgo, sorry for late response, just saw your message. Did you set the delegate ? `cell.delegate = self` ?

Comment: @NeverHopeless Could you give me a hand? I understand it but can't seem to execute it

Comment: Actually I got it working with a little tweaking, thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! You make my day. The world of programming is ugly and beautiful at the same time xD

Comment: Great Work Thank you for your detail answer with explanation.

Comment: when using the IBAction what should you put for Sender?

Comment: @Junaid, not sure if i understood your question fully, perhaps this might be something you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5578139/objective-c-what-is-a-id-sender

Answer (score 11):

The answers proposing a delegate or instance variable are correct, but, however, in most cases it is not important to use a special view controller to present the new controller.
In these cases the following solution is much simpler: Just use the applications root view controller:

```
UIViewController* activeVC = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;
[activeVC presentViewController:'new view controller'
                       animated:YES
                     completion:NULL];
```

Comment: this won't always work with if you structure the table view and cell as not being in the root view controller heirarchy "Warning: Attempt to present <SetOpenViewController: 0x7ffda2f5c280> on <MasterViewController: 0x7ffda2d60450> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Answer (score 1):

`presentViewController:` message is there for Viewcontroller. Do delegate the control from Cell to viewController and use the same line would solve your problem. UITableViewCell does not responds to `presentViewController:` message.

Answer (score 1):

You need a `UIViewController` to present from. There are a few things you can do here. One would be to create a custom delegate protocol with a `changePicturePressed` callback method. Then you can assign the containing view controller as that delegate and perform the presentation in the delegate method.

The other thing you can do is pass the `UIViewController` into your cell during initialization and set it as a weak property. Then you can perform the presentation directly from inside the cell using that property.

Answer (score 1):

Make IBOutlet of your button

Then in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` give target to the button

```
CustomCell *customCell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellIdentifier"];
[customCell.yourButton addTarget:self action:@selector(yourButtonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Answer (score 1):

One other way to do this is pass reference of the controller of the CustomCell to the CustomCell and use that to present the new controller.

Swift:

`CustomCell.swift` :

```
class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    // Rest of the class stuff

    var parentViewController: UIViewController? = nil

    gotoNewControllerBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(gotoNewController), for: .touchUpInside)

    func gotoNewController() {
        let newViewController = NewViewController()
        parentViewController.present(newViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

`ViewController.swift`:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellIdentifier") as CustomTableViewCell!

    cell.parentViewController = self;

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need viewcontroller for presenting the view. You cannot present viewcontroller on tableviewcells.