# Load or Push viewcontroller from tableviewcell class

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, storyboard, uicollectionview

I have added collection view in a UITableViewCell. My UITableViewCell subclass is the UICollectionViewDelegate.
Now if I try to load or push a view controller using the below code:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    ExhibitDetailsViewController* detailViewController = [self.storyboard  instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"exhibitDetail"];
    detailViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
}
```

I get the error: "storyboard not found"

How can I push or load a UIViewController from a UITableViewCell subclass?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22904164/presentviewcontroller-from-custom-tablecell-in-xib

Comment: Got solution using above link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to either pass your navigation controller instance through to the collectionView cell and use it there to push(bad, lazy idea)

OR

Create a protocol delegate to inform your ViewController that your CollectionView selected something and push from the ViewController.