# Presenting view controller from .xib file

Tags: swift, swift3

I am trying to present another view controller from the `.xib` file, but it does not let me. I am getting an error inside the function : `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)`

That's how i declare the `cell` :

```
 let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CustomViewCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! CustomViewCell
```

and then I call :

```
cell.delegate = self
```

This call couse an error : `Cannot assign value of type "MyViewController" to type "shareInfo?"`

Then in my `.xib` file i do have :

```
protocol shareInfo : NSObjectProtocol {
    func loadNewScreen(controller: UIViewController) -> Void
}
```

Inside the class `CustomViewCell` :

```
weak var delegate: shareInfo?
```

and then the method :

```
@IBAction func shareLocation(_ sender: Any) {
        let vc = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [testLabel.text!], applicationActivities: nil)
        if delegate?.responds(to: Selector(("loadNewScreen"))) != nil {
            delegate?.loadNewScreen(controller: vc)
        }
    }
```

Any one knows whats going on ?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

Also I do have this function in `MyViewController`

```
func loadNewScreen(controller: UIViewController) {
        self.present(controller, animated: true) { () -> Void in

        };
    }
```

I was following this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22904164/presentviewcontroller-from-custom-tablecell-in-xib/22904272#22904272)

**SOLUTION**

Ok, I've solved my problem -> protocol has to be added into `MyViewController : ... , shareInfo, ... { ... }`.

Comment: how do you want to presend view controller on cell? that does not make any sense, think again if what are you doing is what you really want

Comment: Have you followed this thread? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22904164/presentviewcontroller-from-custom-tablecell-in-xib/22904272#22904272

Comment: @Lu_ .Xib files contains your custom cells - u might use them in few controllers without creating new cells all the time. I would like to send information from one of my controller via `UIActivityViewController`. / @NeverHopeless yes i did, even with this line `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` it does not help - same error.

Comment: @NeverHopeless please edit your answer with telling ppl to add the protocol to the header of class.