# How to get a selected value from dictionary through tableView?

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, tableview

I have a dictionary with the same keys:

```
var food = [["item" : "Burger", "image": "burger"],
            ["item" : "Pizza", "image": "pizza"],
            ["item" : "Lunch", "image": "lunch"],
            ["item" : "Coffee", "image": "coffee"]],
```

And it is used in my table view. Each cell dispalys a name.

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! Cell

    let foodObjects = food[indexPath.row]

    cell.background.image = UIImage(named: foodObjects["image"]!)
    cell.nameLabel.text  = foodObjects["item"]

    return cell
}
```

And what I want, is **item value** from selected cell be passed to second View Controller.
I know that I can do this throughout this function, but I cannot get a value from selected item. Could somebody help me?

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row

    let resVC = segue.destination as! RestaurantVC //second View controller

    let selectedItem = food[indexPath.["item"]] // How to do this??
}
```

Comment: when will you call this performSegueWithIdentifier ?

Comment: did you get correct indexpath ?

Comment: I call it when I click on cell

Comment: @luk2302 does not work

Comment: Use the delegate method of tableView ,didSelectRow() .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a property in RestaurantVC like this

```
var selectedItem:String!
```

then try this

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row

    let resVC = segue.destination as! RestaurantVC //second View controller

    resVC.selectedItem = food[tableview.indexPathForSelectedRow.row]["item"] // How to do this??
}
```

Comment: Something like this works: 

`let selectedItem = food[indexPath!]["item"]`

And when I print it, it's correct selected item.
But when I try assign it to label in new viewController, it crash:

`resVC.selectedItem.text = selectedItem`

**error: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value**

Comment: @belab try printing selected Item in prepare for segue method.

Comment: I did it, and it's not optional, or nil. Correc value, for example: _Pizza_

Comment: Have you declared string property in second view controller?

Comment: Yes. `@IBOutlet var selectedItem: UILabel!`
Maybe it is about Delegates? or It has no matter?

Comment: No. It is an IBOutlet for a label. You need to create a property like this in second view controller `var selectedItem:String!`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143272/discussion-between-rajeshkumar-r-and-belab).

Answer (score 2):

Create property like

var selectedItem on your controller.

On did select save that item to selectediItem.

Than use it in prepare segue method.

Answer (score 1):

use this method to select a specific object from the tableview

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

 //print(food[indexPath.row].first?.value)
            }
```

Comment: Or `food[indexPath]["item"]`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find the selected indexpath from `override func  prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)` function. you can use `tableView.indexPath(for cell: UITableViewCell)`. Try the following code

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
{

        let destinationViewController = segue.destination as! RestaurantVC

        if let selectedCell = sender as? UITableViewCell
        {
            let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: selectedCell)
            let foodObjects = food[indexPath.row]

        }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```
var food: [Dictionary<String, String>] = [["item" : "Burger", "image": "burger"],
            ["item" : "Pizza", "image": "pizza"],
            ["item" : "Lunch", "image": "lunch"],
            ["item" : "Coffee", "image": "coffee"]]
```

and you can set `selectedItem` in controller `resVC` by following code

```
resVC.selectedItem = food[indexPath]["item"]!
```

or

```
let selectedItem = food[indexPath]["item"]
if let selectedItem = selectedItem {
    resVC.selectedItem = selectedItem
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A possiblity to check out [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22904164/presentviewcontroller-from-custom-tablecell-in-xib/22904272#22904272). Use delegate to retrieve the data from selected cell (which you have passed to cell on `cellForRowAtIndexPath` like `cell.nameLabel.text  = foodObjects["item"]`) and in the delegate event perform segue to move to new controller and pass the data you received in as a parameter to event. So it will be like:

```
func foodItemCellSelected(using foodItem: [String]) // Delegate event of custom cell
{
    self.selectedFoodItem = foodItem; // Retrieve selected item and save it in VC
    self.performSegue(.....);  // Perform segue
}


override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row

    let resVC = segue.destination as! RestaurantVC //second View controller

    resVC.foodItem = self.selectedFoodItem
}
```