# Objective-C get item from sender

Tags: objective-c

I have this method here:

```
- (IBAction)checkBoxTapped:(id)sender forEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{

    NSLog(@"%@", sender);
}
```

this is what sender is returning...

[image]

My question is how do I get the value of _checked

Checkbox is a class

Please Help

Comment: `Checkbox *checkBox = (Checkbox *)sender;`, then `BOOL isCheckBoxChecked =  checkBox.checked`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Objective C: what is a "(id) sender"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5578139/objective-c-what-is-a-id-sender)

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the interface we can only guess what the getter method is for that property.  As it's `BOOL`, and following convention, it's probably called `isChecked` as it's *probably* declared as:

```
 @property (readonly, getter=isChecked) BOOL checked;
```

Therefore, simply access the `isChecked` method (the `NSAssert()` is entirely optional):

```
NSAssert([sender isKindOfClass:[Checkbox class]], @"Expected a Checkbox instance");
Checkbox *checkbox = (Checkbox *)sender;
if (checkbox.isChecked) {
    // Do thing
}
```

Comment: this gives me an error...No visible @interface for 'Checkbox' declares the selector 'checked'

Comment: @user979331 Where is `Checkbox` declared (please edit your question)?

Comment: Try `isChecked` instead of `checked`.

Comment: @rmaddy Highly likely, however `Checkbox` is a custom class is it not and I am not privvy to its interface.

Comment: @rmaddy Having said that I've edited my answer to use `isChecked` as that is most likely.

Comment: But wouldn't it still be just `checked` when using property syntax and `isChecked` when using the getter method call?

Comment: @rmaddy No it would be the same in both cases wouldn't it?  Or am I missing something?

Comment: @trojanfoe OK, I just tried a few examples. If the property's getter is defined to be `isChecked` then if you use the getter method call, it must be `[self isChecked]`. If you use the property syntax, it should be `self.checked` but since you can call methods with no parameters using the property syntax, using `self.isChecked` does work but I personally feel it's wrong. Either use the property as `self.checked` or the getter method as `[self isChecked]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace id with Checkbox class in a method signature like that:

```
- (IBAction)checkBoxTapped:(Checkbox *)sender forEvent:(UIEvent*)event {
    NSLog(@"%@", sender.checked ? @"Checked" : @"Not checked");
}
```

Probably, you are not going to connect this method to another control that is not a Checkbox.

Also you need to move `checked` property to header file (public interface) of Checkbox class