# How use delegate for button in cell table?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a standard method, that forms the cell inside table:

```
- (SearchTableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    cell.button.tag = 3;
}
```

There is button inside cell with action:

```
- (IBAction)changeName:(id)sender {
    // GOTO
}
```

How to change the name of the button after I clicked on it

Comment: `UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender; if (button.tag == 3){//set button title}`?

Comment: @Larme, that's probably the whole answer. You care to make that an answer? :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Objective C: what is a "(id) sender"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5578139/objective-c-what-is-a-id-sender)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it :

```
- (IBAction)changeName:(id)sender {
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;

    if (button.tag == 3) {
        [button setTitle:@"Your title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}
```

Don't forget to link your method to your button in the nib.

Comment: I have not difference tag

Comment: Dear @Pipiks, make note that button is on tableview cell. So button action will only be handled with Protocol Delegate way or Add target to button in CellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: why don't you just use `–(IBAction)changeName:(UIButton *)sender {...}`...?

Answer (score -1):

**Using protocol Delegate method**
Code for custom cell .h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@protocol CustomCellProtocal <NSObject>
 -(void)CellButtonClicked:(UIButton *)sender;
@end

@interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell
   @property(weak) id<CustomCellProtocal>delegate;
   - (IBAction)BtnClicked:(id)sender;
@end
```

code for custom cell .m file

```
#import "CustomCell.h"

@implementation CustomCell
@synthesize delegate;
  - (IBAction)BtnClicked:(id)sender {
      [delegate CellButtonClicked:sender];
   }
@end
```

**Another simplest way**
I suggest you to create custom cell having Button. Create outlet for that button in custom cell class.
Then in cellForRowAtIndexpath() add target to that button like follow

```
[CustomCell.buttonOutlet addTarget:self action:@selector(BtnClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Then handle your logic in BtnClicked method.

```
-(void)BtnClicked:(UIButton *)sender{
     if(sender.tag == 1){
        [sender setTitle:@"Hello" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 }
}
```

I strongly suggest, second way is best for your case. And cell will be dequed with identifier. so no need to worry.

Comment: That is horrible, not only is this not anwering the question at all, nor does it adhere to code conventions. Also, this adds a new target on every call to `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexpath:`, so the button may fire the action(s) more than once.

Comment: Actually cell is dequeReusableCellWithIdentifier.... Secondly by setting tag to each button as of indexPath.row we can identify each button of the record and perform login in same TargetAction method